# What does it means when a pointer comes by the end of a variable (pointer*)?

Tags: c, pointers, syntax, structure

I have gone through pointers, but what does it means when a pointer comes by the end of a variable like this.

```
struct student_record_node 
{
  struct class_record* record_;
  struct class_record_node* next_;
};
```

Comment: `by the end of a variable` which variable?

Comment: It's not at the end of a variable. `record_` is the variable `class_record` is the `struct` name.

Comment: It means you have a pointer to that type, but the pointer is at the end of the type, not the variable. So the node struct contains a pointer to a record, and a pointer to the next record node-it's a singly-linked list.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thank you much apprecited.

Answer (score 4):

That is no *end of variable*. `student_record_node` is a user-defined data type, specified using the *structure specifier* `struct` keyword.

To quote from [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_(C_programming_language)) regarding the same, (*emphasis mine*)

> A `struct` in the C programming language (and many derivatives) is a complex data type declaration that **defines a physically grouped list of variables to be placed under one name in a block of memory**, allowing the different variables to be accessed via a single pointer, or the struct declared name which returns the same address.

In your case,

```
struct student_record_node 
{
  struct class_record* record_;
  struct class_record_node* next_;
};
```

is a declaration of a user-defined type `struct student_record_node` and you can create a variable of that type by saying

```
struct student_record_node stu_record;  //stu_record is the variable name
```

Comment: `struct` introduces a _structure specifier_, not a definition. Strictly speaking, you don't define a `struct`, but _specify_ it. If used alone (`struct { int i; };`, you have  a declaration. So, any `struct` definition would involve defining an object of `struct` type.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a pointer of type `struct class_record` and `struct class_record_node`

You are misinterpreting end of a variable.

Comment: Thank you everyone.